# how to show custom values on x-axis in recharts?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

```
 <LineChart
    width={400}
    height={200}
    data={data}
    margin={{
      top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, 
    }}
  >
    <CartesianGrid  />
    <XAxis dataKey="x" /* tick={false} *//>
    
    <YAxis  />
    <Tooltip content={tooltipContent}/>
    
    <Line type="monotone"  dataKey="y" strokeWidth={1} dot={false} activeDot={{ r: 5 }} />
    
  </LineChart>
```

my dataset includes just the decimal points(23.444,54.6665,..). I want to divide the axis into equal 10 halves (10,20,30,...100). How can I show these values on axis?
below is the image of the chart
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TatGP.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use custom values on the XAxis, or custom `ticks`, you need to use the following props on your XAxis component:

- Specify the type of the values to number with `type="number"`
- Supply the tick values `ticks={[10, 20, 30, [...], 100]}`
- And the domain to specify the limits `domain={[10, 100]}`

In the end, your XAxis should look like this:

```js
<XAxis
  dataKey="x"
  type="number"
  ticks={[10, 20, 30, [...], 100]}
  domain={[10, 100]}
/>
```